# Vertical Menu items shifting to same line when window size increased

Tags: menus, css

I've tried messing with float and clear but could get anything to keep this from happening:

[image]

"Fun" and "Shop" are supposed to be on different lines.

Here's the CSS involved with the nav/ul/li/a:

```
nav ul {
background-color:#fff;
font-size:70px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
line-height:100%;
}

.navbar nav {           left:2%;
position:fixed;
}

nav ul li {}

a {color:#000000;}
a:visited {color:#000000;}
a:hover {color:#0088ce;
}
```

Comment: Use `display: block;` accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `nav ul li` definition appears to have bad syntax. Try this:

```
nav ul li {

    a {color:#000000;}
    a:visited {color:#000000;}
    a:hover {color:#0088ce; }
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with bad syntax, nor your answer. Firstly, nested declarations are NOT ALLOWED in CSS. Your answer is LESS / SASS / whatever syntax, NOT CSS. Secondly, you solved it by adding `clear: both` — *not* by cleaning up syntax. To clarify: adding `clear: both` to an element ensures it is neither to the left nor to the right of a floating element, and therefore is positioned below it.